# Assigning empty array and distinctUntilChanged issue

Tags: rxjs

I have next rxjs code that checked if query `length is > 1` then the rest operators execute:

```
 o$.pipe(
    filter((query) => query.length > 1),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((query) => {
      return this.data.query(query);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.localData = data; //returns array
  });
```

I want to assign `this.localData = []` in case if `query.length === 0`. So thought to use operator like `tap()` above `filter()` where I would put that logic, but `distinctUntilChanged()` braking the logic because in case if `cur` value is equal to `prev` value the `localData` will be lost:

```
  o$.pipe(
    filter((query) => query.length > 1),
    tap((query) => {
      if(query.length === 1) {
        this.localData = [];
      }
    }),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((query) => {
      return this.data.query(query);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.localData = data; //returns array
  });
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even use the filtering step if you still want to pass data to the subscriber of the observable? I suggest to just perform the logic in the switchMap operator. In case of query.length > 1 the querying for data will be performed. In all other cases an empty array is passed to the subscriber:

```
  o$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((query) => {
      return query.length > 1 ? data.query(query) : of([]);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.localData = data; //returns array
  });
```